# railway booking program in python

Tags: python

I'm working on this project in python where I'm trying to code a system that allows the user to book, cancel, print train tickets and also save everything they've done to a separate file that the program reads every time it opens and the re-saves it with the new information when it is closed. I'm stuck because I don't know what to do next, I've defined a class for reservations and also some methods within the class. I'll eventually attempt to code a GUI, where the user just clicks on the button with the seat number they want to order to book it and so on. Here's what I've done so far, I'm a new programmer so please be kind, I need suggestions on what I should do next, I'm I on the right track or do I need to code in another way? Here's what I've done so far:

```
class Reservation:
    def __init__ (self, seatCol, seatRow, department, destination, departure, price):
        self.__seatCol = seatCol
        self.__seatRow = seatRow 
        self.__departement = departement
        self.__destination = destination
        self.__departure = departure
        self.__price = price

    def selectDeparture(departure):
        #Asks the user to pick a departure

    def selectDestination(destination):
        #Asks the user to pick a destination

    def selectSeat(seatCol, seatRow, department): 
        #Asks the user to pick a seat and checks if it's already booked

    def ticketPrice (price):

    def printBookedTicket:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dead set on using classes for this project, make sure to follow a good [tutorial on Python OOP programming](https://www.google.com/search?q=tutorial+on+python+oop+programming&oq=tutorial+&aqs=chrome.1.0j69i59j69i65l3j69i57.7134j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

However, I recommend learning some Python fundamentals before tackling OOP stuff. 
If I was going to make this program, I would put all my data in a dictionary and make functions that could do all my editing of the data. Once you get this, if you feel like wrapping a class around it, you could.

Start with a simple command line interface to manipulating your data, something like:

```
ticket_booker.py add John Smith
>> Departure : ?
>> Destination: ?
>> (etc).
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your reply, so I should firstly create separate dictionaries for departures, destinations and seats?

Comment: Look at how dictionaries work first and then structure your data how you like.